# How to resolve audio cutting out, returns if pause and play

Tags: itunes, macos, audio, music

Listening to audio in iTunes, after approximately 30 seconds, the audio will sort of crackle, then go out completely. The song will continue playing, without sound. If I press pause and play or switch to a different track the audio plays normally, again for about 30 seconds, and then fizzles out again.

Running iTunes 12.4.3.1 under OSX 10.11.6

UPDATE: Tested audio in gpodder, and same result, so it is not an iTunes only issue.

Comment: Is it a problem with your speakers?

Comment: Are these Bluetooth Speakers?

Comment: Nope, internal speakers.